# running Pdf2htmlEX on linux using php

Tags: php, linux, exec, pdf2htmlex

Kindly I request your help on the following issue:
I am using pdf2htmlEX to convert my pdf files to HTML. The tool is working perfectly in WAMP; however, when I implement it on my Linux server, the tool is not working.

My php code:

```
<?php $cmd=  "pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 sample.pdf sample.html";
exec($cmd, $output, $return);?>
```

Note that I have tested exec command and it is enabled. Moreover, the directory is rewritable.

I am running the code from my browser

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Rasha

Comment: "Kindly check the attached file" - There is no file attached. Best is to provide source inside your question.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code. Thank you in advance.